# Using UIKIT Modal to get Variables (instead of prompt)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, uikit, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) and triggering a prompt on clicking on date. So if I click on September 30th I get two prompt boxes.

I currently receive two variables in my javascript using the following code:

```
        var title = prompt('Job Title:');
        var project = prompt('Project Title:');
```

I'm trying to use [UIKIT modal component](https://getuikit.com/docs/modal.html) to create a single modal with the fields to get the variables (rather than the two separate prompt popups).

I can display the modal and disable the prompts, but the fullcalender function continues to run. It cannot find the var title and throws up the error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined**

The prompt pauses the processing of the code until a variable is provided. My modal does not.

What is the correct way to use a modal to replace a prompt. What code is best used to pause the running of the JavaScript until the save button is pressed and variables added to the fields?

**Below are more details on the code used:**

I replaced the above JS code with:

```
$.UIkit.modal('#workcal-add-modal').show();
```

and have the following modal:

```
<!-- This is the modal -->
<div id="workcal-add-modal" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>

        <form class="uk-form">

            <fieldset data-uk-margin>
                <input type="text" placeholder="project Name" id="wc_add_project_title">
                <select>
                    <option>Project 1</option>
                    <option>Project 2</option>
                </select>
                <button class="uk-button">Save</button>
            </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `promise` based approach, where you create a promise, and resolve it when the user clicks in `save` or reject when user cancels or closes dialog.

See this: https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are creating these vars in a function that then ends, and so the stored variables are deallocated.

At the top of your script, create two vars.

```
    var title;
    var project;
```

When your code need to populate these vars, then use the code:

```
    title = prompt('Job Title:');
    project = prompt('Project Title:');
```

Later, when your code needs to use them, they will be initialised with the values you desire, as long as you don't use them before that time.

Without more of the code, and to see where they are being created and used, it is hard to tell why `title` is undefined at the time you are trying to use them. It may be scope or that at the time you populate them, the calendar is not created like in a case where you pass in a closure at init time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this very simply after all.

I just wrapped the remaining javascript within a function that only triggers when the save button has been clicked.

```
        $("#modal_save").on("click", function(){ ... all the code here ... });
```